# What are the kalaas of arka (sun), soma (moon), bahni (fire)?

Tags: gods, mantras, worship

In Puja mantra, we get...

> Am Arkamandalaaya dvadasa-kalaatmane namah ( meaning I worship Arka with twelve kalaas), Um somamandalaaya shodashakalatmane namah (I worship soma with sixteen kalaas), mam bahnimandalaaya dasakalaatmane namah (I worship Bahni with ten kalaas).

My question is: What are these kalaas of Arka, Soma and Bahni?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good question. The mantra is used while offering the Vishesha-Arghya to the deity.

The first uses AM, the second UM and the third MAM, so they are actually three separate parts of A-U-M.

Arka means Surya or the Sun. Arka has twelve kalaas.

> The twelve kalaas of Surya are tapani,taapini,dhumraa,marichi.jvalini,ruchi,sushumna,bhogadaa,vishvaa,vodhini,dhaarini, kshamaa.

Soma means Chandra or the Moon. Soma has sixteen kalaas.

> The sixteen kalaas of soma are amritaa, maanadaa, pusha,tusti, rati,dhriti,sasini,chandrika,kaanti,jyotsna,sri,priti,angadaa,purnaa,purnamritaa.

Bahni means Agni or fire

> The ten kalaas of bahni are dhumrarchi,ushmaa,jvalini,jvaalini, vishfulingini,susri, surupaa, kapilaa,havyavaahanaa,kavyavahanaa.
>
> अग्निकला (Ten parts or appearances of fire) :धूम्रार्चिरुष्मा ज्वलिनी ज्वालिनी विस्फुलिङ्गिनी । सुश्री: सुरूपा कपिला हव्यकव्यवहे अपि ॥ यादीनां दश- वर्णानां कला धर्मप्रदा अमूः॥

Hope this answers your question.

(Reference: Sri Sri Omkar Sahasra Lipi, compiled by Kinkar Madhava Ramanuja Jeyara,Delhi Jayaguru sampradaya, page 417).

Answer (score 5):

The Kalas of Vahni (Agni), Arka (Surya) and Soma (Chandra) are mentioned in the Mahanirvana tantra's Chapter 6, in the context of preparing the Sri Patra and Samanya argha.

**Vahni Kalas:**

Vahni has 10 parts (Kala-s).

> Then the six parts of the body should be worshipped in the six corners
>   of the hexagon. Then worship the triangle, with the Mula−Mantra, and
>   then the Shakti of the receptacle with the Maya Vija and Namah (23).
>   Wash the receptacle with the Mantra Namah, and then place it (as in
>   the case of the jar) on the Mandala, and worship in it the ten parts
>   of Vahni with the first letters of their respective names as Vijas
>   (24). **These parts, which are ten in number viz., Dhumra, Archih,
>   Jvalini, Sukshma, Jvalini, Vishphulingini, Sushri, Surupa,
>   Kapila,Havya−kavya−vaha** should be uttered in the Dative singular,
>   and followed by the Mantra Namah (25−26). Then worship the region of
>   Vahni (in the adhara or receptacle) with the following:

**Arka Kalas:**

Surya has 12 parts.

> Then, taking the vessel of offering and purifying it with the Mantra
>   Phat, place it on the receptacle, and, having so placed it, worship
>   therein the twelve parts of the Sun with the Vijas, commencing with
>   Ka−Bha to Tha−Da (28). **These twelve parts are Tapini, Tapini,
>   Dhumra, Marichi, Jvalini, Ruchi, Sudhumra, Bhoga−da, Vishva, Bodhini,
>   Dharini, Kshama (29)**. After this, worship the region of Sun in the
>   vessel of offering with the following

**Soma Kalas:**

Soma has 16 parts.

> Then the worshipper should fill the cup of offering three−quarters
>   full with wine taken from the jar, uttering the Matrika Vijas in the
>   reverse order (31). Filling the rest of the cup with water taken from
>   the special offering, let him worship with a well−controlled mind the
>   sixteen digits of the Moon, saying as Vijas each of the sixteen vowels
>   before each of the sixteen digits spoken in the dative singular,
>   followed by the Mantra Namah (32).
>   **The sixteen desire−granting digits of Moon are Amrita, Pranada, Pusha, Tushti, Pushti, Rati, Dhriti, Shashini, Chandrika, Kanti,
>   Jyotsna, Skri, Priti, Angada, Purna, and Purnamrita (33)**.

All the above verses are from **Mahanirvana Tantram's Chapter 6**.